# Tag links for Meta posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

When you have a Meta tag, it's treated as an SO tag. This tag is clearly Meta, yet:

[profile-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/profile-page)

Takes you to SO.

Can we add an option that allows us to define an MSO tag? Maybe:

```
[meta-tag:profile-page]
```

If we just checked whether the tag is meta or not, then some tags would be more difficult to get to from Meta (tags on both sites - which one to go to? [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) for example)

Should this become an option, and if so, what would be the best/most convenient way to do it?

Comment: We have used our time machine to implement this feature precisely as you described. You’re welcome. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can already use `[meta-tag:tag]` in posts, and it will link to the appropriate meta-tag.

E.g. `[meta-tag:discussion]` will be rendered as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), `[meta-tag:status-completed]` as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), `[meta-tag:profile-page]` as [profile-page](/questions/tagged/profile-page), etc.